# In app purchase query

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am working on in app purchase which works fine but I want to know that user have purchased product or not at the launching time of application.

How should I know this.
If anybody knows please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check the following link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044777/how-to-get-check-if-a-product-is-already-purchased-using-in-app-purchase-in-ios

Comment: Thank you this link helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a "receipt" in the user defaults (`NSUserDefaults`) then check if the receipt exists when the app is launched.

**HOWEVER** plainly using `NSUserDefaults` is prone to hacking so you can use a secure version of user defaults from [here](https://github.com/matthiasplappert/Secure-NSUserDefaults).

another solution (and the recommended one if done correctly) will be to store receipts on a server and read available receipts when the app launches. (Note though that if the user has turned device data off you won't be able to read them).

Comment: Is there any method is available in store kit to know that this user have purchased the product using device Id or Apple Id?

Comment: You can issue a restore products request as already mentioned but again, if the data is off this won't help you and leave the user with no purchased content

Comment: if I am storing the receipt in NSUserDefaults then if user will uninstall and reinstall app the NSUserDefaults gets empty in that case how do I know that user have purchased my product or not.

Comment: This is why you are required to implement a "restore previous purchases" mechanism. (Usually a button that after being tapped issues a request to restore purchased products)

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to get the user's purchase receipt and check all the products they have purchased.

You can follow the [guide here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW2) to see how you can validate receipts locally.

[This document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html) explains the structure of the receipt - the in-app purchase fields have the product identifiers which can be used to find out which IAPs the user has access to.